# Angular Dynamic Component Creation not rendering dynamic child components

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-dynamic-components

We've built a rather fancy dynamic component creation framework to build out complex forms based on json data.  We have components that get created via

```
const questionComponent = FieldComponentMap[childField.shortName];    
viewContainerRef.createComponent<QuestionComponent>(questionComponent);
```

Those components may create child components of their own, etc, etc.  It's all very elegant, and we like the design.  We've got the whole thing "working", but it's not working well.  Child, or perhaps grandchild components often don't render the first time around until something changes on the page.  I'm sure we're just missing something simple, but we could use some more eyes to help us find what we're doing wrong.

We've tried moving all the dynamic component creation out of ngOnInit and into ngAfterContentInit, but that didn't help.  We obviously want the complete form to render immediately.

Here's a StackBlitz demonstrating our issue (drastically simplified from our framework)...
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-appwts?file=src/app/components/array-question-wrapper.component.ts)

Comment: I don't know if there is a problem with the StackBlitz you created but if you look at the console, there are a few error beign thrown

Comment: We've had a devil of a time making sense of those errors and why the form actually starts to work when the form is interacted with.  It's like the errors only happen at that point in time, and at another point, they go away?

Comment: So those are not 'StackBlitz' errors? you are getting those same errors on your development environment as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're lost in the hierarchy.

To be more precisely, you're operating a wrong instance of `FormGroup` in

**array-question-wrapper.component.ts**

Try replacing

```
this.createChildQuestionComponents(this.formGroup);
```

with

```
this.createChildQuestionComponents(this.formGroup.get(
     [this.formArrayName, this.formArrayIndex]) as FormGroup);
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-etvwyi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fcustom-renderer.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Farray-question-wrapper.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fparent-array-question.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

### Another option

When working with dynamically creating forms you don't need to wrap all your `ng-template`s with `formGroup`, `formArrayName` directives. They are not tied to your child dynamically created controls anyway.

So:

**parent-array-question.component.ts**

Replace

```
componentRef.instance.containingControl = this.formGroup;
```

with

```
componentRef.instance.containingControl = arrayItem;
```

**array-question-wrapper.component.ts**

template should be:

```
<div class="child-questions">
  <ng-template appQuestionHost></ng-template>
</div>
```

or just `<ng-template appQuestionHost></ng-template>` if you don't need any additional classes here or you can use host element to style it.

**[Forked Stackblitz 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f725fo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fcustom-renderer.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Farray-question-wrapper.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fparent-array-question.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fsimple-array-question.component.ts)**

Comment: Excellent job finding the problem. We found it as well just a few hours before you posted this.  I was going to write up a solution, but you've done a great job. We were passing the wrong FormGroup from ParentArrayQuestionComponent to ArrayQuestionWrapperComponent. I definitely want to look at your Option 2, but I haven't had time yet. I find it a pain having to rebuild the hierarchy in the templates, especially for child components inside FormArrays.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with template portals that were instantiated within a component that was dynamically added. Setting a timeout to associate the template portal within the dynamically created component fixed it. I am not perfectly satisfied with that. But, it may give a hint as to why your controls are not being recognised.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).